# React Component without Function or Class?

Tags: javascript, class, reactjs, components, stateless

On occasion, I have both seen and wrote some React code like this.

```
const text = (
  <p>
    Some text
  </p>
);
```

This does work, but are there any issues with this?

I know I can't use props this way, but if all I'm doing is rendering something simple like a paragraph, I don't see why I would need to make it a functional component or extend `React.Component`

My current reason for this is because I need to pass in a paragraph or two as placeholder text and I can't just pass in plain text.

Comment: I think it is best practice to use it that way because you want the best performance but also the shortest way to write your code. Your element doesn't use props and is just a presentational so it is best to keep it minimal as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a **react component**, it is just a variable in which `JSX` is stored:

```
const text = (
   <p>
      Some text
   </p>
);
```

As per [**DOC**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/introducing-jsx.html):

```
const element = <h1>Hello, world!</h1>;
```

> This funny tag syntax is neither a `string` nor `HTML`.
>
> It is called JSX, and it is a syntax extension to JavaScript. We
>   recommend using it with React to describe what the UI should look
>   like. JSX may remind you of a template language, but it comes with the
>   full power of JavaScript.

`props` will be available only in **React component**, either in Functional Component or a Class based Component.

> Why React is required in this if it is not a react component?

We can store JSX in any variable and it will get transpiled by [babel](https://babeljs.io/), and get converted into `React.createElement`.

As per [DOC](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#specifying-the-react-element-type):

> JSX just provides syntactic sugar for the React.createElement()
>   function.
>
> Since JSX compiles into calls to React.createElement, the React
>   library must also always be in scope from your JSX code.

Example: when we write:

```
var a = <div> Hello </div>
```

[Result](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code=var%20a%20%3D%20%3Cdiv%3E%20Hello%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E) of this will be:

```
var a = React.createElement(
  "div",
  null,
  " Hello "
);
```

Comment: not exactly. This is a react element. You can not assign it to a variable without `React` in scope.

Answer (score 0):

This code is just storing a paragraph element with the text inside it into the variable `text`. It's not a component, functional or otherwise. Use it in a React component like you would standard Javascript:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="some-text">
            { text }
        </div>
    );
}
```